# Symfony: how to assign data to a template in an inheritating controller-action?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have `TheParentController` and the inheritating `TheChildController`, which should assign `$moreData` to the template, but the `render()` method should be called in `TheParentController`.

Is there any function/service for this case? I expect anything like

`$this->get('templating')->assignDataForTemplate('moreData', $moreData);`

```
class TheParentController 
{
    public function myAction($param1) {
        return $this->render('template.html.twig', array(
            'someData' => $someData
        ));
    }

}
```

-

```
class TheChildController 
{
    public function myAction($param1) {
        // !
        // Is there any function like "assignDataForTemplate"?
        $this->get('templating')->assignDataForTemplate('moreData', $moreData);
        // /!
        return parent::myAction($param1);
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid something like

```
// ...
public function myAction($param1, $moreData = null) {
    return $this->render('template.html.twig', array(
            'someData' => $someData,
            'moreData' => $moreData
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattHB Symfony is so powerful and I cannot imagine, there is no out-of-the-box solution for this issue. Or maybe my architecture isn't in the Symfony way. I try to avoid workarounds like this. But thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no such way to do this currently. If you go through the sources, you'll see that calling `$templating->render()` is actually calling `TwigEngine->render()`.That calls `Twig_Template->render()` which outputs the template to the client.

I fully understand why you might be using HMVC but I believe this approach might be overcomplicating things for you. If you have common code between controllers - just create a static class which can be called directly. Afterwards move your common logic/code there and call it whenever you need it.

Otherwise, you might need to stick with the code you're trying to avoid (or similar workaround) for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, so that the parent is unaware of the child.

```
<?php    
class TheParentController {

    public function myAction () {
        $data = $this->getMyActionData();
        return $this->render('template', $data);
    }

    protected function getMyActionData () {
        return [
             'someDefault' => 5
        ];
    }
}

class TheChildController extends TheParentController {

    // If using annotation based routing override myAction
    // with call to parent function and new @Route tag in doc block

    protected function getMyActionData () {
        $parentData = parent::getMyActionData();
        return array_merge($parentData, [
            'childData' => 11  
        ]); 
    }
}
```